# Poisson Coin tossing on to a page question

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I am having difficulties with a question that goes as follows:

"The mean no. of misprints on a page of area 400 $cm^2$ is 10, A silver dollar of area 20 $cm^2$ is tossed on the page at random. Find the approximate probability that it covers at least one misprint"

I believe that one is supposed to use poisson variable but I cannot seem to reconcile the probability together. Could someone please explain please ?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder how many persons of youngness in reading this site have ever seen a silver dollar.  (U.S. one-dollar coins were made of silver from 1792 through 1963 and until the 1850s were legally pegged to the value of the Spanish silver dollar.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told that there are $10$ errors per $400\text{ cm}^2$. Then the rate of errors $\lambda$ is $$\lambda = \frac{10\text{ errors}}{400\text{ cm}^2}.$$
Then the number of errors per unit area $N(A)$ follows a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda|A|$, $$N\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda|A|)$$
where $|A| = 20 \text{ cm}^2$, the 'size' of $A$.

Hence, if $N(A)$ is the number of errors that the coin covers, then
\begin{align*}
P(N(A)\geq 1) &= 1-P(N(A) = 0) \\
&= 1- e^{-\lambda|A|}\frac{(\lambda|A|)^0}{0!} \\
&= 1-\exp\left\{-\frac{10}{400}\cdot 20\right\} \\
&= 0.3934693.
\end{align*}

Comment: The rate is $\lambda = \tfrac {10}{400} \operatorname{cm}^{-2}$, the area of the coin is $\lvert A\rvert=20\operatorname {cm}^2$, and hence $\lambda\lvert A\rvert = \tfrac 1 2$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks a lot!! I self-studied stochastic processes and you helped me realize my logic was incorrect. That's why I post here, for the peer review. Thanks for the insight!!

Comment: No accounting for margins?

Comment: @A.S. Haha, don't scare me. Are you being serious? Next you'll say 'No accounting for corners?'. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

The average number of misprints in a page of 20 $cm^2$ is 0.5. Hence our Poisson distribution will be of the form $P(x=n)=((0.5)^n/n!)e^{-0.5}$ The probability of getting at least one misprint is the complement of getting *0* misprints, hence $1-((0.5)^0/0!)e^{-0.5}=1-e^{-1/2}$ Note that $\lambda$= average in a Poisson distribution $(\lambda^n/n!)e^{-\lambda}$.